# adding textbox to a masterpage content page in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, textbox, master-pages, addition, runat

i am trying to put a textbox inside content page :

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
<br /><br />

<br />
<form>
<asp:TextBox runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
</form>

</asp:Content>
```

and i am getting an error:
"Control 'ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00' of type 'TextBox' must be placed inside a form tag with runat=server."

when i'm trying to put runat="server" like this:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
<br /><br />

<br />
<form runat="server">
<asp:TextBox runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
</form>

</asp:Content>
```

i'm getting that error:

"A page can have only one server-side Form tag."

sombody can help please?

Answer (score 0):

Your master page also has a `<form runat=server>` tag.  Either remove it from the master page or from your content page.  You can only have one.  I recomend you open up MasterPage.master and remove the form tag.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a Runat="Server" tag in your asp:Content tag. There is no need to have the tag in your Form and TextBox since they are within the same Master Page. In a Master Page you can only have one reference to the Runat="Server" tag.

Comment: You can have more than one, actually. Only one can be `Visible` at any given time.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can should the `form` tag and place your textbox inside the `asp:Content` directly